Can Ruffle Flash Emulator Be Used for an Old Flash Application
I’m looking into using the Ruffle Flash emulator to revive an old Flash application we developed. This isn’t a game but a comprehensive tool with various features for creating, editing, and saving artifacts.
Our main goal is to allow users to experience and explore the features of this application without dealing with user logins or saving functionality through Ruffle.
Could someone advise if Ruffle is a suitable solution for running a complex Flash application like this? If so, could you provide any guidance or best practices on how to get started with using Ruffle for this purpose?
Thank you!

No, it is a horrible idea. Ruffle is still not substituting Flash Player  completely (https://ruffle.rs/compatibility) and even when they supposedly do, they cannot guarantee they are not missing some things. For you that means releasing an app with guaranteed glitches (and probably some functionality loss) without any power over them or ability to fix them.
